# Spring Boot Application issue with rabbitmq in docker

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to build a event driven microservice with spring cloud stream using rabbitmq. In my case, rabbitmq is running in docker.

Docker commands used to run below container

`docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit --publish 15672:15672  rabbitmq:3`

Then going to bash mode of container I fired below command:
`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`
in order to start `management-plugin`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                          NAMES
b2bc315c44aa        rabbitmq:3          "docker-entrypoint..."   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp   some-rabbit
```

So I can access docker from browser on `localhost:15672`

But when I start the Spring Boot application it is not making queue and exchange. Please check the stack trace.

Stack-trace

```
  o.s.i.codec.kryo.CompositeKryoRegistrar  : configured Kryo registration [40, java.io.File] with serializer org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.FileSerializer
  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'integrationMbeanExporter' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'integrationMbeanExporter': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration.monitor:name=integrationMbeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter]
  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'rabbitConnectionFactory': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=rabbitConnectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory]
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel nullChannel
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=nullChannel]
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel output
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=output': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=output]
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel errorChannel
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=errorChannel]
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageHandler errorLogger
  o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Located managed bean 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.integration:type=MessageHandler,name=errorLogger,bean=internal]
  o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase -2147482648
  r.t.b.demo.source.GatewayApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
  s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@56cfe111: startup date [Mon May 29 15:07:40 JST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4fe767f3
  o.s.c.support.GenericApplicationContext  : Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@67de7a99: startup date [Mon May 29 15:07:40 JST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
  r.t.b.demo.source.GatewayApplication     : Started GatewayApplication in 0.189 seconds (JVM running for 10.957)
  o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : Failed to declare exchange: Exchange [name=output, type=topic, durable=true, autoDelete=false, internal=false, arguments={}], continuing... org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'gateway:8181.output' has 1 subscriber(s).
  o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
  o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'gateway:8181.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
  o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
  o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147482647
  o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
  s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8181 (http)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you pointing to rabbit from spring boot? What hostname:port?

Comment: As rabbitmq is running with default settings, I have not done special settings in spring boot application.yml

Comment: Looking at the docker output, I would say that only port `15672` is accessible from the outside. All the other ports aren't exposed. How did you start the container. Also instead of only adding a vague message you want to add the full stack trace / debug information you have.

Comment: Thanks, could you also explain how you started the activemq container?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Docker image for RabbitMQ that has the management plugin (see https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/), in your case `rabbitmq:3-management`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in above container I added plugins using `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. Please check edited version of question.

Answer (score 0):

I have been wrestling with using rabbit mq running in docker and I think you will need to make some entries in your spring boot application.properties file to overcome the connection problem.

It looks like your exchange is not being created due to connection refused.  You need to overcome that.  In the rabbit web admin console you will need to create a user with permissions.  Then add some configuration in application.properties :

```
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=the_user_name
spring.rabbitmq.password=user_password
```

Good luck.